# How do i make a texture move/slide? For a waterfall texture, ofcourse

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor, edit-mode, compositing-nodes

What nodes do i need for a sliding texture which goes down, just like a waterfall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply project a water texture (with transparent background) onto a plane that you've bent:

[image]

Then keyframe the location values of the Mapping node to make the water move along the plane:

[image]

Also keep in mind that if you've enabled the *Only Show Selected* option in the *Dope Sheet* you'll need to keep the node selected to see the keyframes, same thing for the *Timeline*, keep the node selected.

Comment: Excuse me, how do i keyframe mapping? i tried this once but i failed. Thanks, but i need some help on that front.

Comment: enter the location value you want, put your cursor over the value and press "i", then move your blue bar in the Timeline, enter a new location value and keyframe again

Comment: Thank you. I will do that now.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you've enabled the Only Show Selected option in the Dope Sheet you'll need to keep the node selected, same thing in the Timeline, keep the node selected

Comment: i'd upvote if i could